# How to combine query parameter observable and form observable using Angular and RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs5, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have a List of Post with Pagination that I subscribe to the query parameter `?page=` to recalled the service API

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {

        const page = params['page'];

        // on query parameter change, call the API service here


    });
}
```

Now, I have a new requirement where User can also filter the list by selecting Category dropdown using **Reactive Form**.

Using Reactive Form, I can subscribe to the observer using this code here

```
onChanges(): void {
  this.myForm.get('category').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    // on form value change, call the API service here
  });
}
```

My question is, how can I simplify this using Angular and RXJS?

The method in the example above not really DRY because the are calling the same API, only with different request parameter

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) operator:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  combineLatest(
    this.route.queryParams, 
    this.myForm.get('category').valueChanges
  ).subscribe(([{ page }, category]) => {
     // on any change call the API service here
  });
}
```

Side note: Don't forget to unsubscribe in the `onDestroy` hook, or use the `takeUntil` operator

Comment: Thanks your answer point me to the right direction of understanding RXJS